# Rotated my engine backwards when changing timing belt, jumped timing?

Tags: engine, timing-belt, crankshaft

I just did the timing belt on my seat ibiza 2004 1,4 petrol and accidentally rotated the engine backwards trying to get the crankshaft bolt off as it was really tight. I tried to hold the crank pulley still with a crank pulley holder but it slipped a couple times and the engine rotated maybe half a rotation or so counter-clockwise. I got it off and changed the belt and tensioners and the car ran fine afterwards.

The service manual does tell you to rotate it in the direction of rotation when checking timing after timing belt replacement, but there's no caution or warning against doing it counter-clockwise so I'm not sure. Since the car is a manual transmission it is possible for the engine to spin backwards if say I stalled on a hill and the car rolled back without pressing the clutch so you'd think that they would have thought of this in the design.

Is it possible to jump timing or damage the engine somehow?

For reference:

Car: 2004 Seat ibiza 6L

Engine code: BBY (NA 1,4 litre petrol)

Mileage: 110000 km (63000 miles)